# Permission issues in Linux during compilation of source code

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, compilation, linux-kernel

I am trying to do a compilation by placing the source directory in a partition which is external to my ubuntu partition. When I kick off the compilation, I get permission denied issues as shown. Can someone please let me know how I can resolve this?

```
root@machine1-desktop:/media/E8202E47202E1CD6/IceCreamSandwich#    '/home/machine1/bin/build.sh' 
 Using: androidu
/home/machine1/bin/DL10_build.sh: line 34: ./customize.sh: Permission denied
/home/machine1/bin/DL10_build.sh: line 35: [: ==: unary operator expected
/home/machine1/bin/DL10_build.sh: line 38: ./miyabuild.sh: Permission denied
/home/machine1/bin/DL10_build.sh: line 40: ./customize.sh: Permission denied
Time duration: 0 mins
```

Answer (score 2):

When you say it's on an external partition, what type of file system is it?  (What does running 'mount' say about it?)  If it's a FAT or FAT32 partition, they don't support the executable permission for files, so chmod +x won't work on them.  You'll need to tell the filesystem to pretend files are executable, e.g.:

```
mount -t vfat -o umask=077 [device] [location]
```

Comment: `root@anees-desktop:/media/E8202E47202E1CD6/MSM8960_IceCreamSandwich# mount /media/E8202E47202E1CD6/
mount: /dev/sda4 already mounted or /media/E8202E47202E1CD6 busy
mount: according to mtab, /dev/sda4 is already mounted on /media/E8202E47202E1CD6
root@anees-desktop:/media/E8202E47202E1CD6/MSM8960_IceCreamSandwich# `

Comment: can you please let me know what I should try using(based on logs I provided) in place of [device] [location] so that I can give a try

Comment: What does running just 'mount' with no parameters say?